# Showing the equality of two dimensional integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Does anyone know how to show the equality of the integrals at hand?

\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 (z(1-z))^{-\epsilon} \int_0^1 y^{1-2\epsilon}(1-y)^{-1-\epsilon}\left[\frac{2}{1-zy}\right] dydz \\
&=\int_0^1 (t(1-t))^{-\epsilon} \int_0^1 s^{1-2\epsilon}(1-s)^{-1-\epsilon}\left[\frac{(1-s)}{t(1-t)s^2}\right] dsdt.
\end{align}

Since the problem is part of a more advanced job, I can provide further about it, if required.

Edit: Just to clarify things: I know the exact result of both integrals and furthermore how to obtain them. Unfortunately I am not able to transfer one integral into the other by substitution.

Comment: The integrals are both expressed as the hypergeometric function ${_3F_2}$ with some parameters. Or at least, I'm fairly sure of that

Comment: Sure, the first one can be expressed as the hypergeometric function and the second one in terms of gamma functions. But exists a transformation between the integrals?

Comment: Since they are equal, it sure does. That's why I mentioned hypergeometric functions, there's a lot of general transformations known for them, so you might be able to find the one you need

Comment: Good point. I always refer to Abramowitz and Stegun. Any other textbook suggestions for transformations of the hypergeometric function?

Comment: Honestly, I usually just search online. Though do you really need to use substitution? You can derive the hypergeometric form for the first integral in two steps, you will have a product of two beta functions multiplied by ${_2 F_1}$, while the second integral is immediately seen to be a product of two beta functions and ${_2 F_1}$. I'd wager their arguments turn out to be the same, which is proof enough. We get ${_2 F_1}$ instead of ${_3 F_2}$ in the first case because there's a cancellation of parameters.

Comment: The relevant formulas from Wikipedia are: $$\mathrm {B} (b,c-b)\,_{2}F_{1}(a,b;c;z)=\int _{0}^{1}x^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-b-1}(1-zx)^{-a}\,dx\qquad \Re (c)>\Re (b)>0$$ $${}_{A+1}F_{B+1}\left[{\begin{array}{c}a_{1},\ldots ,a_{A},c\\b_{1},\ldots ,b_{B},d\end{array}};z\right]={\frac {\Gamma (d)}{\Gamma (c)\Gamma (d-c)}}\int _{0}^{1}t^{c-1}(1-t)_{}^{d-c-1}\ {}_{A}F_{B}\left[{\begin{array}{c}a_{1},\ldots ,a_{A}\\b_{1},\ldots ,b_{B}\end{array}};tz\right]dt$$

Comment: I tried to do this myself, but it's late and I probably made some mistakes, as my result didn't check out numerically. So I leave it up to you

Comment: @Schnarco Do you want to prove that the integrals are equal without finding closed forms or to prove that the closed forms that you have are equal? If the latter, you should provide the closed forms (both integrals reduce to a rational combination of gamma functions).

Comment: @Maxim The former one is my goal. But  it is not urgent, since I also succeded with the latter method.